# EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: No data nodes with HTTP-enabled available (HTTPS issue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, elasticsearch, pem

I generated public and private key to establish connection between a cluster node and `AWS` cluster and communication was successfully set up. Now I am trying to create an `index` and write data into it to installed and configured on `AWS` `Elasticsearch` and getting the following error:

> Error summary: EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: No data nodes with HTTP-enabled available

The port that is used to access `Elasticsearch` is `443`, so it is `HTTPS`, so I suspect that the following needs to be done:

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#ssl-and-authentication

I need to generate `.pem` file somehow out of `public` and `private` keys that I already got? I am not sure whether I am on the right track and if I am, I do not know how to get `.pem` file out of the available keys (To just generate public, private keys, certificate and pem files together is easy, there are tutorials for that, but I already got private and public keys and do not want to regenerate everything because I am not in charge of `AWS`).

I read over the error:

https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster/issues/116

and tried supplying `es.nodes.client.only=true` but it fails with similar error: no `HTTP` nodes available. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, the key was to set `es.nodes.wan.only` to `true` and make sure that all of the environment variables are correct if you use them to substitute port, host. In my case, there was a confusion with the environment variables.